# Cómo puedo insertar un dato en SQL SERVER recorriendo cada una de las cabeceras de la tabla y si esta coincide con la seleccionada se inserta el dato

Tags: sql-server, table, where

tengo el siguiente probale con una  tabla en SQL SERVER y necesito de su apoyo.
tengo una tabla llamada Pagos en esta tabla se muestran los siguientes campos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que busco es que al momento de **registrar** un pago de un beneficiario este sea desacuerdo al mes y el año  que sea seleccionado y por ejemplo si es en el mes de agosto del año 2022 se inserte la cantidad del pago, pero aun no se como hacerlo, soy un novato en esto así que les pido su ayuda.
De ante mano gracias por su atención

Comment: Hola Fran. Interesante... Qué has intentado? Por favor copia y pega las sentencias sql en forma de texto

Comment: Hola. Supongo que conoces el IDbeneficiario. Hay que buscar el script de la sentencia update... creo que puede tener una estructura más o menos así... update (Año, Febrero) from tabla Set (valor, valor) where IDbeneficiario = 220001. No me se los scripts bien pero espero te sirva mi aporte relámpago

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.